# How to define and use a class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've almost never coded in CSS before, and I saw this in the power point of my web development class (it's originally written in French so I'm not sure if my translation is completely accurate):

```
The <p> with the property class=indented and inside the element <td> will have the following CSS properties:
td p .indented {text-indent: 50px;}
```

So I tried using this code to test it but it's not working:

```html
    <body>
        this is the body of the document <br>
        <style>
            td p .indented {font-weight: bold; color:red}
            td {color:blueviolet}
        </style>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> 1 </th>
                <th> 2 </th>
                <th> 3 </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>test</p></td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td><p class=indented>test</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

all 3 `test` are displayed in purple, but nothing is displaying in red and bold text. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: First, you should have `class="indented"` with the quotation marks, second `td p .indented` isn't the same as `td p.indented`. In your example, you're targeting an element with the class indented inside a p, not a p with the class indented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a slight typo in your CSS rule. `td p .indented` targets elements with the class `indented` that are descendants of a `p` elements, which in turn is a descendant of a `td` element.

What you're likely looking for is to target `p` elements with the class `indented` which are children of a `td` element. Remove the whitespace between `p` and `.indented` in your selector definition:

```html
    <body>
        this is the body of the document <br>
        <style>
            td p.indented {font-weight: bold; color:red}
            td {color:blueviolet}
        </style>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> 1 </th>
                <th> 2 </th>
                <th> 3 </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>test</p></td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td><p class=indented>test</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write CSS in 3 ways : internal CSS written as a `style=""` attribute right beside the other attributes of your `<p>` tag
Another way is by embedded stylesheets method which you have opted in you code, giving `<style` tag in `<head>` section of the `<html>` document. Here, the only flaw is:
that you have given a space between `p` and `.indented` due to which it is read as if `<p>` contains a child element to which `.indented` class has been applied, whereas you wanted to apply the class to `<p>` itself and access it.
And, the third way is external stylesheets that is maintaining the styles in a separate file other than the html file.
So, the following code will fix the problem for you. All the best!

```html
<body>
        this is the body of the document <br>
        <style>
            td p.indented {font-weight: bold; color:red}
            td {color:blueviolet}
        </style>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> 1 </th>
                <th> 2 </th>
                <th> 3 </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>test</p></td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td><p class=indented>test</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are quite there with your code, there is only a minor typing flaw `td p .indented` needs to be `td p.indented` as it changes the whole meaning of CSS descendants selector theory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `,`. Your code should be like

```
<body>
        this is the body of the document <br>
        <style>
            td, p.indented {font-weight: bold; color:red}
            td {color:blueviolet}
        </style>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> 1 </th>
                <th> 2 </th>
                <th> 3 </th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><p>test</p></td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td><p class="indented">test</p></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
   </body>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what the OP was intending. This will make all `td`, `p`, and `.indented` elements bold and red.

Answer (score 0):

To define a class in HTML tags you'll have to use this type of syntax:
`class = "classname"`

So try changing the
`class=indented`
to
`class = "indented"`